# How to develop dynamic usercontrol in asp.net with C#?

Tags: c#

I want to develop dynamic usercontrol in asp.net with C#.

Comment: what is a dynamic usercontrol according to you ?

Comment: This question can be placed on hold under the official close reasons Too Broad or Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)